# How is the normalized trace defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

As the title says I need to make sure I understand exactly what a normalized trace is.  Everywhere I've looked, including here I find references to the trace of a normalized matrix, but I am not comfortable simply assuming a normalized trace = trace of normalized matrix.

Edit: I should have specified that the matrix in question is a square 3x3 matrix

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: @Mariano For my case it's coming from this [paper](http://www-vis.lbl.gov/Publications/2015/LBNL-177531.pdf): section 3.2.3.  Relating to a matrix representing a deformation of a volume by a gradient of a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently I just didn't spend quite enough time looking.

According to this book **Clifford Algebras: An Introduction** (by D. J. H. Garling) the normalized trace of a square matrix is just the trace of the matrix divided by the dimension of the matrix.

For a 3x3 matrix A the normalized trace would be the tr(A)/3.